# Screensaver on local display, while user use Remote Desktop on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, screensaver

we have some meeting rooms that run windows7, when the PCs are not in use, we want to show a screensaver that shows images  (kind of like an internal info-screen station), and this works fine. when a user logs in, and does not use the PC for 1 minute the screensaver starts fine.

BUT: if someone remote desktop to this PC (which we do all the time, as long as the meetingroom is not in use), the screen saver does NOT show the entire time someone is using the pc via remote, and also when the remote user disconnect, or log out, the screen saver never comes back.. only when a local user log in, does the screen saver start again.

so, my question is: how can I make the local screen(s) run a screen saver, during and after a RDP connection.

Comment: wish someone had any good ideas here